# Swift Cannot append to subscript on type JSON

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting JSON data using SwiftyJSON, and got a changeable array using:

```
let worldDataGenJSON = JSON(data:data)
worldDataGenBlocks = worldDataGenJSON["blocks"]["x"].arrayValue as Array
```

With this, I can append to worldDataGenBlocks easily like:

```
worldDataGenBlocks.append([
    "y": [:]
])
```

I created a new array inside worldDataGenBlocks called "y", but I'm not able to append to it

```
worldDataGenBlocks[0]["y"][0].append([
    "bid": 0,
    "id": 0,
    "fid": 0
])
```

It would say:

> Value of type 'JSON' has no member 'append'

I tried to set it this way too, but with no avail:

```
worldDataGenBlocks[cX]["y"][cY] = [
    "bid": 0,
    "id": 0,
    "fid": 0
]
```

Every time I print "worldDataGenBlocks" it would show empty "y" arrays.

Please help.

Comment: You may try https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: @Joe I'm already using SwiftyJSON, the problem is that the data I receive cannot be append in the subscript